# lisp iterative function always returns nil

Tags: lisp, iteration, let

this function is supposed to count the number of times that the element 'a' appears in a list, but is not working:

```
(defun iter-a_count (lst)
   (let ((count 0))
        (dolist (x lst)
                (if (equal x 'a) 
                    (setf count (+ count 1)))
         count )))
```

This function always returns nil. May I ask where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The value returned from `dolist` macro is the third "argument" to it, i.e.

```
(dolist (iterator iterable result) forms)
```

Where `iterator` is updated every iteration to be the `car` of next cell of `iterable`, after all list cells have been visited, `result` is returned.

You didn't specify the result, and the default value for result is `nil`. I'm not sure what the purpose of count in the last line is - perhaps you wanted to return the count - in which case, put it after lst.

Several more things you want to consider:

```
(setf x (+ x 1))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(setf x (1+ x))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(incf x)
```

It is more idiomatic to write

```
(when x forms)
```

instead of

```
(if x true-branch)
```

Because if you will later want to add more expressions to the `true-branch`, you will have to wrap them in `progn` - and that just clutters the code.

Also, what you are doing (or seem to be doing), can be replaced by a call to `count-if` with a proper predicate.

```
(defun count-a (list)
  (count-if #'(lambda (x) (equal x 'a)) list))

(count-a '(a b c d a b a d a c b d e))  ; 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I entered count as the third argument, and now the function works. Thanks for the information on count-if also. Now I'll attempt a recursive version of count-a.

Answer (score 2):

> May I ask where I am going wrong?

Indentation (as in, you are indenting wrongly): you wrote

```
(defun iter-a_count (lst)
  (let ((count 0))
    (dolist (x lst)
      (if (equal x 'a) 
          (setf count (+ count 1)))
      count)))
```

But I think you meant

```
(defun iter-a_count (lst)
  (let ((count 0))
    (dolist (x lst)
      (if (equal x 'a) 
          (setf count (+ count 1))))
    count))
```